# Push/Present a viewcontroller from right,the viewcontroller cover 3/4 part of previous viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push, presentviewcontroller

I want to do this:I push or present a viewcontroller called B, the previous viewcontroller called A, but B won't cover full screen, it's 3/4 width of screen's width,the left 1/4 width of A turns dark,when I tap this area,B can be dismissed,is this possible? Appreciate for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try out some open source libraries to achieve this.
The best library that I have come across is [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

There is a [TUTORIAL](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) on AppCoda featuring this library.  Check that out for more info.

FYI,

If you still prefer a DIY approach, take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path).

Comment: not exactly fit my question,but still an excellent response,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller in Storyboard. Goto Attributes Inspector -> Simulated Metrics -> Size -> freeform

Change the width of the B view controller to whatever you want.